# Express js Railway Deployment

Tags: mongodb, express, deployment, hosting, web-hosting

i am deploying my express js app (with hbs template engine ) in railway for the very first time . i configured a mongo db server as database for my app . later i cloned my github repo to my railway app . The build finished successfully without any errors  but in deployment it gave me a error . i dont know what is this error so i am providing a screenshot [image]

when i am running the server as localhost in my pc and connecting to railway mongo url it is working fine

Comment: Have you tried to use http://localhost:27017 instead of http://127.0.0.1:27017 ?

Comment: I deployed my database in railway and they gave me a connection url and i copied the url and added as environment variable in my repo . Also for the first few seconds as you can see in console that the connection is established but the error is happening after 1 mins or something